# Selenium python поиск элемента по style

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте имеется HTML-код

```
<ul class="regions">                                                                                            
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> ....</li>                                                                                                                         
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> ....</li> 
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> ....</li> 
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> ....</li> 
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> ....</li>  
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> ....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> ....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> ....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> ....</li>
```

Нужно выбрать только те элементы, которые со style="display: list-item;
Как это можно сделать? Мой код выбирает все элементы, так как ссылаются по классу

```
regions=window_div.find_element_by_class_name("regions")
regions_all=regions.find_elements_by_class_name("modal-row")
for region in regions_all:
    region_a=region.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
    region_a.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Думаю, что можно как-то с XPath, но не знаю как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать с помощью xpath элементы, у которых `style` атрибут содержит `list-item`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from lxml import html

doc = html.fromstring("""<ul class="regions">
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> 1....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> 2....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> 3....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: list-item;"> 4....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> a....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> b....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> c....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> d....</li>
   <li class="modal-row" style="display: none;"> e....</li>
</ul>
""")
print(*[el.text for el in doc.xpath("//*[contains(@style,'list-item')]")])
print(*[el.text for el in doc.xpath("//attribute::*[contains(., 'list-item')]/..")])
```

Comment: спасибо, а если есть еще строчка <li class="block-title" style="display: list-item;">Регион</li> которую, не надо выбирать

Comment: @danilshik Отфильтруйте по признакам, которые в вашем случае смысл имеют (по классу, по тексту)

Comment: я имел ввиду, можно ли в одном выражении xPath так сделать? А пока пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде regions=window_div.find_element_by_class_name("regions")
        top=regions.find_elements_by_class_name("modal-row")
        regions_all=top.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@style,'list-item')]"), но выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath

Comment: @danilshik если вы спотыкаетесь на AttributeError, то задайте отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос

Comment: @jsf, ничего лучше не придумал, как игнорировать первый элемент for region in regions_all[1:]: (так как он всегда сверху). Если вы знаете более лучший способ, напишите пожалуйста, чтобы я разобрался

Comment: @danilshik это однозначно AttributeError не исправит.

Comment: можешь посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/784780/python-selenium-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-xpath